# How to tell std::future if std::promise exist in C++?

Tags: c++11, packaged-task, std-future

I create a `std::packaged_task`, push it to a `std::list` and return its `std::future` to users, like this:

```
future_t emplace(...)
{
    //...
    auto task = std::make_shared<std::packaged_task<return_t()>>(
                std::bind(std::forward<F>(f), std::forward<Args>(args)...));
    tasks.emplace_back(task);
    std::future<return_t> result = task->get_future();
    
    //...
    return result;
}
```

In another thread, we may clear the tasks list at anytime:

```
// another thread
std::list<task_t> temp_{};
tasks.swap(temp_);
```

But users may call std::future still:

```
auto result = emplace(...);
// do something and the tasks list has been clear in anthor thread
auto ret = result.get();
```

Get a exception error as std::promise has been destroyed:

```
C++ exception with description "std::future_error: Broken promise" thrown in the test body.
```

I can use a exception expression to avoid the program broken:

```
try
{
    auto ret = result.get();
}
catch (...)
{
}
```

Can I avoid `std::future_error` without exception expression?
My question is: Is there any other method to detect if the std::promise exist?

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid there is no direct way to detect if the promise still exists. If you must do that, you may have to do some additional work to keep the state of the `task`(or the corresponding `future`), which is more complicated than the current solution. All `future`s are by default invalid. Whenever you execute the task, you mark the `future` is *valid*. Whenever you're to get a result through a `future`, check if it's valid.

**Notice: you have to handle the synchronization of this state since this state is shared between different threads.** That sounds wired, right? You're going to share another data **outside** the pairwise promise and future. I don't recommend and don't think it's necessary to do so.

When you're using `std::promise` and `std::future`, all exceptions should be handled in the `std::future::get`.